# How to catch write aborts in python-tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

I want to stream a long database result set through Tornado.
I obviously need a server cursor since its not feasible to load the whole query in memory.

So I have the following code:

```
class QueryStreamer(RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
      cursor.execute("Select * from ...")
      chunk = cursor.fetch(1000)
      while chunk:
          self.write(chunk)
          self.flush()
          chunk = cursor.fetch(1000)        
     self.finish()
     cursor.close()
```

If someone does not read my request till the end? (i.e. `curl ... |head`),
The `get` method keeps happily streaming my data to nowhere. I would expect to get `SIGPIPE` at some point and close database cursor (without running it to the end for nothing).

How can I catch write errors in Tornado?

**Update**: Following suggestion in the answer I've tried the following:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time

class PingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                for i in range(600):
                        self.write("pong\n")
                        self.flush()
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print "pong"
                self.finish()
                print "ponged"

        def on_connection_close(self):
                print "closed"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        application = tornado.web.Application([ ("/ping", PingHandler), ])
        application.listen(8888)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I'm running this file in terminal 1 and in terminal 2 I invoke:

```
curl -s   http://localhost:8888/ping
```

and after first response I hit CTRL-C. But in terminal 1 I see that it happily keeps "pong"-ing and `on_connection_close` never gets called.

Bottom line - still does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make the handler asynchronous and use `ioloop.add_timeout` instead of  `time.sleep`, because that blocks the loop:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen


class PingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    connection_closed = False

    def on_connection_close(self):
        print "closed"
        self.connection_closed = True

    @tornado.gen.coroutine  # <= async handler
    def get(self):

        for i in range(600):

            if self.connection_closed:
                # `on_connection_close()` has been called,
                # break out of the loop
                break

            self.write("pong %s\n" % i)
            self.flush()

            # Add a timeout. Similar to time.sleep(1), but non-blocking:
            yield tornado.gen.Task(
                tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout,
                tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().time() + 1,
            )

        self.finish()
        print "finished"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([("/ping", PingHandler), ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: I see... I need to pass control to ioloop from time to time to get on_connection_close to work. In my original example I'm fetching cursor, so I guess I need to do it in async way. This is not convenient unfortunately. I was hoping that self.write will cal on_connection_close in case of SIGPIPE. Thanks for your detailed example.

Comment: *I guess I need to do it in async way* — yes

Answer (score 2):

Implement the [on_connection_close](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_connection_close) method and have it stop that write loop in your `get` handler.

Comment: Tried this and it does not help - please see an updated answer. Thanks.